# module does not opens unanmed module using quarkus and mongock

Tags: java, mongodb, quarkus, mongock

I get the following issue when starting up quarkus with mongock on java 17:

```
2022-07-22 07:50:57,109 ERROR [io.mon.run.cor.exe.MongockRunnerImpl] (main) Error in mongock process. ABORTED MIGRATION: io.mongock.api.exception.MongockException: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @3c87521
    at io.mongock.runner.core.executor.MongockRunnerImpl.execute(MongockRunnerImpl.java:67)
    at mt.com.my.proj.quarkus.commons.db.mongo.migration.MongoMigrationManager.init(MongoMigrationManager.java:89)
    at mt.com.my.proj.quarkus.commons.db.mongo.migration.MongoMigrationManager_Bean.create(Unknown Source)
    at mt.com.my.proj.quarkus.commons.db.mongo.migration.MongoMigrationManager_Bean.create(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext.createInstanceHandle(AbstractSharedContext.java:111)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext$1.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:35)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext$1.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:32)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.LazyValue.get(LazyValue.java:26)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ComputingCache.computeIfAbsent(ComputingCache.java:69)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:32)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ClientProxies.getApplicationScopedDelegate(ClientProxies.java:18)
    at mt.com.my.proj.quarkus.commons.db.mongo.migration.MongoMigrationManager_ClientProxy.arc$delegate(Unknown Source)
    at mt.com.my.proj.quarkus.commons.db.mongo.migration.MongoMigrationManager_ClientProxy.arc_contextualInstance(Unknown Source)
    at mt.com.my.proj.quarkus.commons.db.mongo.migration.MongoMigrationManager_Observer_Synthetic_d70cd75bf32ab6598217b9a64a8473d65e248c05.notify(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.EventImpl$Notifier.notifyObservers(EventImpl.java:323)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.EventImpl$Notifier.notify(EventImpl.java:305)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:73)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.ArcRecorder.fireLifecycleEvent(ArcRecorder.java:130)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.ArcRecorder.handleLifecycleEvents(ArcRecorder.java:99)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.LifecycleEventsBuildStep$startupEvent1144526294.deploy_0(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.LifecycleEventsBuildStep$startupEvent1144526294.deploy(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl.doStart(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Application.start(Application.java:101)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.ApplicationLifecycleManager.run(ApplicationLifecycleManager.java:103)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:67)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:41)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:120)
    at mt.com.my.proj.tenant.TenantGeoConfigServiceApplication.main(TenantGeoConfigServiceApplication.java:13)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.runner.QuarkusEntryPoint.doRun(QuarkusEntryPoint.java:60)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.runner.QuarkusEntryPoint.main(QuarkusEntryPoint.java:31)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @3c87521
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193)
    at javassist.util.proxy.SecurityActions.setAccessible(SecurityActions.java:103)
    at javassist.util.proxy.DefineClassHelper.toClass3(DefineClassHelper.java:151)
    at javassist.util.proxy.DefineClassHelper.toClass2(DefineClassHelper.java:134)
    at javassist.util.proxy.DefineClassHelper.toClass(DefineClassHelper.java:95)
    at javassist.util.proxy.FactoryHelper.toClass(FactoryHelper.java:131)
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass3(ProxyFactory.java:530)
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass2(ProxyFactory.java:515)
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass1(ProxyFactory.java:451)
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass(ProxyFactory.java:422)
    at io.mongock.driver.api.lock.guard.proxy.LockGuardProxyFactory.createProxy(LockGuardProxyFactory.java:92)
```

I am using `quarkus` version `2.9.0.CR1` and `mongock` version `5.1.0`

I have migrtation scripts  that inject the following objects (only, no other custom defined objects)

```
@ChangeUnit(id = "create-global-config", order = "6", author = "me")
public record Migration006GlobalConfigCreation(ClientSession clientSession, ReactiveMongoDatabase mongoDatabase) {
```

Comment: Version 5.1.1 has been released and we believe your issue is fixed

Comment: not sure if i have something else but this seems to still be the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that, mistakenly, the internal JDK packages were removed from the list of package to NOT be proxied.

Nothing to do with Quarkus. It's due to Java 16 modularisation.

That will be updated and released in version 5.1.1 soon

Comment: Released 5.1.2 :)